# multiplying two columns in postgres from summed up columns

Tags: postgresql, multiplication

i have a column which is a sum of a group by. i want to multiply this column to another column using the following query. I tried using a subquery but it does not work.

```
SUM("subq.public"."fpProjects"."capitalTotalSpent")*"public"."currencyYears".curRate"
FROM(
SELECT
Sum("public"."fpProjects"."capitalTotalSpent") AS "total capital spent",
FROM
"public"."fpProjects"
```

I get a syntax error here "Sum("public"."fpProjects"."capitalTotalSpent") AS "total cap"

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Comment: I did try but I still got an error

Comment: Can you post the whole query, and the table definitions? That would really help to solve it. That is if you still need help.

Comment: thank you. But i think it has worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actual table names, but I think something like this is what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(subq.sum_total_capital_spent) * curRate)
FROM public.currencyYears, (
  SELECT Sum(capitalTotalSpent) AS sum_total_capital_spent FROM public.fpProjects
) subq
```